# jQuery and parsing XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I have problem with jquery and xml.
My xml looks like:

```
<cars abc="26">
  <car price="20.000" name="Audi" model="A4" />
  <car price="40.000" name="Audi" model="A6" />
  <car price="15.000" name="BMW" model="Z3" />
</cars>
```

etc.

I would like get all car from Audi and price for this models.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'cars.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('cars>car').each(function(index, val){
        console.log($(this));
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: `$(xml).find('car[name="Audi"]')`?

Comment: Ok (I can do that), but I would like get price etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
$(xml).find('cars>car[name="Audi"]').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).attr('price');
    console.log(price);
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about attr :D